# Nginx - ELB health check fails because of 301

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I have set up ELB health check (port 80) on this uri - `/healthcheck` but the problem is I am getting a **301** because **nginx redirects** all traffic coming at port 80.

My goal is this -

1. Use a simple html file (my app serves this file) for ELB health
   check..
2. When I need to take an instance out of rotation, I just use
       a script to remove this file and so ELB stops sending traffic to this
       instance.
3. Now I can do a deploy. Once all is done, I create the
       file again and things return to normal again

FYI, this is the response I get -

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nginx as load balancer gives you any freedom with custom configuration

Comment: How is your nginx configured? As long as you can serve up a static HTML file of any sort, the ELB checks will handle it. If your page it causing a 301' can you add an exception to your nginx conf to allow that path?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm having this exact problem myself today.